# jekyll front matter variable don't work

Tags: jekyll

I'm starting to use jekyll, but when trying to customize a variable it does not work.
My code

```
---
layout: default
hello: "teste liquid"
---

  <h1>{{ page.hello }}</h1>
```

but this don't work, it does not print anything in html, it leaves empty

do I need to do any additional configuration on jekyll?

Comment: "it does not work" is not a problem description. What happened? Why was that bad?

Comment: it does not print anything in html, it leaves empty

Comment: Did you have a code repository ?

Comment: Please check the Jekyll output for errors. You probably have an error. This code is OK.

Comment: I solved the problem by turning index.md into index.html and creating the variable in index.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing this because I had the same problem and I lost half a day trying to figure out what caused it.

When I installed jekyll and created a new site I got the following file by default: index.markdown with an empty front matter in it (two lines of three dashes each).
I also created an index.html file as the Jekyll tutorial suggested.

Apparently, if you have both files and you try to add front matter to the HTML file the whole site breaks and the default jekyll page is displayed instead of the index.html page.
The solution is to remove or rename the index.markdown file so the HTML file is the only index.
Note, that if you don't add front matter to the HTML page the HTML page is displayed normally (but, of course, the liquid tags {{ }} don't work)

Hope this help.
Thanks to virginiarcrz for pointing this solution out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. There was an **extra space** after toggling a comment '#' tag in the frontmatter of my index.md:

```
---
#title: index
 title: index2
----
```

and I fixed it by removing the space:

```
---
#title: index
title: index2
----
```